# Select multiple rows in table from another row that contains multiple values separated by commas

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one table that contains Titles and Tag ID's called `TaggedTitles`. I have a second table that contains Tags and TagID's. The `TaggedTitles` table has multiple tags that are associated with each title. For example:

`TaggedTitles` table: the `TagID` column associated with the title 'Automobiles' contains: 1,5,7 that represent tags in the Tags table. In this example 1,5,7 represent tags: wheels,paint,carpet. I need to left join the Tags table to return wheels,paint,carpet using the title Automobiles as a parameter.

```
SELECT  
    Tags.TAGS
FROM 
    Tags
LEFT JOIN 
    TaggedTitles ON TaggedTitles.TAGID = Tags.TAGID
WHERE 
    TaggedTitles.TITLE = @Title
```

TitleTable

```
TAG_ID  TITLE       
-------------
  1     FRUIT       
  2     FRUIT       
  3     FRUIT
```

Tags table

```
TAG_ID  TAG     
----------------------
  1     ORANGES     
  2     APPLES      
  3     PEARS
```

Result needed: `Oranges,Apples,Pears` from parameter 'Fruit'

Comment: Ugh...any chance you can fix the data model? Storing delimited strings violates 1NF and is a pain to work with. You will have to split that entire table on your delimited every single time you query it to find a row. Also your where clause above has turned your left join into an inner join.

Comment: I suppose I could. Would it be best to store the title 'Automobiles' on three separate rows with each tag separately? I didn't realize it would be this complicated to use delimited strings in a column.

Comment: If you can share your current architecture and a couple rows of sample data I can show how you can normalize your structure. Once this is normalized querying this will be painless.

Comment: @SeanLange I have changed the data model to look like the table I pasted in the original question.

Comment: So you need a delimited list returned? There are hundreds of examples of using STUFF and FOR XML to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that now. The original question was regarding delimited strings and the suggestion was made to change the data model. That's why I changed the data and copied an example.

Comment: "atomic value: each value in the domain is indivisible as far as the relational model is concerned"   https://opentextbc.ca/dbdesign01/chapter/chapter-7-the-relational-data-model/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try combine XML PATH with STUFF sentence.

For Example:

```
DECLARE @INFO TABLE (TAG_ID int, TITLE varchar(10)) 

INSERT @INFO VALUES (1,'ORANGES')
INSERT @INFO VALUES (2,'APPLES')
INSERT @INFO VALUES (3,'PEARS')

SELECT STUFF((
       SELECT ','+TITLE
       FROM @INFO
       FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1, '') AS FRUITS
```